# Add table row when cell focus lost and cell is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form   [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HUSTLIN/p4qo4rrn/)

```
<table class="table table-timesheet" ng-controller="TimesheetCtrl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="timesheet-project-th">
                    <span class="timesheet-table-head">Project</span>
                </th>
                <th id="timesheet-date-th">
                    <span class="timesheet-table-head">Date</span>
                </th>
                <th id="timesheet-task-th">
                    <span class="timesheet-table-head">Task</span>
                </th>
                <th id="timesheet-timeworked-th">
                    <span class="timesheet-table-head">Time</span>
                </th>
                <th id="timesheet-note-th">
                    <span class="timesheet-table-head">Note</span>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="log-work-block">
                <td>
                    <select class="timesheet-project-list" style="width:98%">
                        <option value="" disabled selected style='display:none;'>Choose a project...</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Task"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Elapsed time"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Note"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

I need to add table row, when I filled at least one cell and focus on input is lost, help me please to solve this, my knowledge of javascript is not good.

Comment: did you try something ??? show us where did you got stuck

Comment: I don't know how to make this, and that's why I post my question

Comment: well you need jquery/js for that

Comment: @Meenesh Jain, I know that, cap.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add tbody tag in your table tag. And add script below.

```
<script>
    $("input").blur(function(){
        if($("input[value!='']").length > 0){
            createRow();
        }
    });

    var createRow = function(){
        $("table tbody").append($("#template").html());
    };

</script>
<script type="text/html" id="template">
    <tr class="log-work-block">
        <td>
            <select class="timesheet-project-list" style="width:98%">
                <option value="" disabled selected style='display:none;'>Choose a project...</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Task"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Elapsed time"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Note"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Is it you want?

Comment: The value attribute isn't – necessarily – updated along with the value *property*, so this may not work as expected or required.

Comment: @DongHoon Kim, I need to add row same as <tr class="log-work-block"> and not in tbody